# swift 2.0 как получить имя image загруженого как background на экран в данный момент

Tags: swift

swift 2.0 как получить имя  image загруженого background_ом на экран

import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var startTimer0003: NSTimer!       //background первичный запуск
weak var startTimer0004: NSTimer!  //backgraund интервалы повторов

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.startTimer0003 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "runMe0002",userInfo:nil,repeats: false) 
    //background первый запуск

    self.startTimer0004 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: "runMe0002",userInfo:nil,repeats: true)
    //background интервал повтора

}

/*************************************************************/    
// xCode марки 7.2
// запуск на iPhone 6+

/**********************  background  *************************/

weak var imBackGroundView: UIImageView?

func runMe0002() {

    if(self.imBackGroundView == nil)

    {

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:
        background[0])!)
        //background = массив тип String, для проверки берется только одно [0] значение

    }

    let imageBackground = UIImage.init(named: background[0]) // все значения для пробы на отклик
    let imageBackground0002 = self.view.backgroundColor!
    let image0002 = UIImage.init(named: background[0])      
    //  let image0002 = UIImage.init(named: "bk0002.jpg") //проба по значению image 
    let imageBackGroundColor = UIImage.init(named: background[0])
 /*********************** switch *******************************************/   
    switch (self.view.backgroundColor)!  // или проба из списка откомментированных = все одинаково...
        // switch (UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: background[0])!))
        // switch (self.view.backgroundColor! = UIColor(pattertnImage: UIImage(named: background[0]))!)

    {
        // 0
    case (self.view.backgroundColor)! === image0002:
        print("view.backgroundColor works_0")
        //0.1
    case self.view.backgroundColor! !== UIImage!(imageBackground!):
        print("view.backgroundColor works_0.1")
        //0.2
    case self.view.backgroundColor! !== UIColor(patternImage: (UIImage?(imageBackground!)!)!):
        print("view.backgroundColor works_0.2")
        //0.3
    case imageBackGroundColor !== "bk0002.jpg":
        print("It works_0.3")
        //0.4
    case image0002! :
        print("It works_0.4")
        //0.5
    case UIColor(patternImage: (UIImage?(imageBackground!)!)!):
        print("It works_0.5")
        //0.6
    case "bk0002.jpg":
        print("It works_0.6")
        //0.7
        //case background[0]: ОШ String
        //   print("It works_0.7")
        //0.8
    case UIColor(patternImage: (UIImage?(imageBackground!)!)!):
        print("It works_0.8")
        //0.9
    case UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: background[0])!):
        print("It works_0.9")

        // 1
    case self.view.backgroundColor! != background[0]:
        print("view.backgroundColor works_1")
        // 2.0
    case self.view.backgroundColor! !== UIImage(named: background[0]):
        print("view.backgroundColor works_2.0")
        // 2.1
    case self.view.backgroundColor! !== UIImage.init(named: background[0]):
        print("view.backgroundColor works_2.1")
        // 2.2
    case UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: background[0])!) != background[0]: //"bk0002.jpg":
        print("view.backgroundColor works_2.2")
        // 2.3
    case self.view.backgroundColor! !== UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "bk0002@3x.jpg")!):
        print("view.backgroundColor works_2.3")
        // 3
    case self.view.backgroundColor! !== UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: background[0])!):
        print("view.backgroundColor works_3")
        // 4
    case UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: background[0])!) !== true:
        print("view.backgroundColor works_4")
        // 5
    case UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: background[0])!) !== 0:
        print("view.backgroundColor works_5")
        // 6
    case UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: background[0])!) !== "bk0002.jpg":
        print("view.backgroundColor works_6")
        // 7
    case UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: background[0])!) !== "bk0002@3x.jpg":
        print("view.backgroundColor works_7")
        // 8
    case self.view.backgroundColor! != UIImage(named: "bk0002@3x.jpg")!:
        print("view.backgroundColor works_8")
        // 9
    case imBackGroundView == background[0]:
        print("view.backgroundColor works_9")
        // 9.1
    case self.imBackGroundView != background[0]:
        print("view.backgroundColor works_9.1")

        // 10
    case self.imBackGroundView != UIImage(named: background[0]):
        print("view.backgroundColor works_10")
        // 11
    case self.imBackGroundView === UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: background[0])!):
        print("view.backgroundColor works_11")
        // 12
    case self.imBackGroundView === UIImage(named: "bk0002.jpg"):
        print("view.backgroundColor works_12")
        // 13
    case self.imBackGroundView !== self.view.backgroundColor:
        print("view.backgroundColor works_13")
        // 14
    case self.imBackGroundView !== UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:
        background[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(background.count)))])!):
        print("view.backgroundColor works_14")
        // 15.0
        // case self.view.backgroundColor!.isEqual(UIColor(patternImage: UIImage?(named: image0002))):
    case self.view.backgroundColor!.isEqual(UIColor(patternImage: (UIImage!(image0002))!)):
        print("view.backgroundColor works_15.0")
        // 15.1
    case self.view.backgroundColor!.isEqual(UIColor(patternImage: (UIImage.init(named: background[0]))!)):
        print("view.backgroundColor works_15.1")
        // 15.2
        // case (UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: background[0]))!) isEqual image0002: // = ОШ
        //   print("view.backgroundColor works_15.2")

        // 16
        //case self.view.backgroundColor?.isEqual (UIColor(patternImage: (UIImage!(named: background[0]))!)):            
        //case self.view.backgroundColor!.isEqual(UIColor!(patternImage: UIImage!(named: "bk0002.jpg"))!):            
        //case self.view.backgroundColor!.isEqual(UIColor(patternImage: (UIImage!("bk0002@3x.jpg"))!)):

        //      print("view.backgroundColor works_16")

    default :  print("view.backgroundColor no result") // все принт идут в консоль...

    }   //скобка  закрытия  switch первый



    /***********************    **************************/

    startTimer0003.invalidate()

    // startTimer0004.invalidate()

}  // скобка func runME0002

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}   // покомпилировать - будет ссылка на ya.disk

---

```
weak var imBackGroundView: UIImageView? // = imageBackground

func runMe0002() {

var imageBackground = UIImage(named: background[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(background.count)))])

    if imageBackground! != UIImage(named: background[0])            
    {
    print("imageBackground works_0") }

    else { print("view.backgroundColor no result")        
    }   //скобка  закрытия  if

    if(self.imBackGroundView == nil)           
    {            
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage!(imageBackground))            
    } //скобка if (self.imBackGroundView == nil)
```

} // скобка func runMe0002()

Comment: либо я вопрос не понял, либо ответ такое сделать нельзя, после загрузки изображения в память система сама не знает откуда изображение взялось

Comment: давно подозревал, что не все ладно в датском королевстве...а вот эти штуки никак нельзя приклеить= ? func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {...  и  просто func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)... ведь система берет из массива по индексу...мне не обязательно имя файла - достаточно и по численному значению...уже сколько времени тупо пытался как-то проскользнуть но ничего путного не вышло...@Max Mikheyenko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартно данный функционал не предусмотрен. И если изображение отображается, имя файла получить нельзя, плюс не факт, что изображение из файла, может оно загружено из сети.

Но вы можете создать переменную и хранить в неи имя файла, который берете. Можете создать свой класс, унаследованный от `UIImage` и в поле класса указывать имя файла.

Comment: попробовал по рецепту = почему-то отрабатывает наоборот т.е. если условие background[0] не выполнено - print("imageBackground works_0") а если условие выполнено т.е. в background экрана загружено нужное значение - background[0] - print("view.backGroundColor no result")  = так бывает = ? и еще по этому совету - нет ли чего-либо типа примера или похожего...@VAndkJ